# Spark running in local

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, apache-spark

The master parameter for a SparkContext determines which cluster to use. I can specify local, which sets Spark to run locally with one worker thread, or specify local[k], which sets Spark to run locally with K worker threads (24 cores in my case). Why two ways are giving me similar running time? Am I not understanding it correctly? I am trying to run MLIB packages on data sets, with a bit RDD transformations.

Comment: It could be that the overhead of generating extra threads is more expensive than the speed up you get.  This is especially possible if your data size is not too large.  When I run spark locally (using python) I get a rather lengthy start-up time for spark ~1-2 seconds.  If the problem isn't large, this is far more time consuming than the actual computation.

Comment: Hi Travis,Thanks for this. I am very new to Spark. So could you please also try to explain to me briefly that how exactly the multithread/running in cluster is working? How can multi-thread(local[k]) run faster than local alone? My question is I am not adding in any extra memory, why sending RDD pieces to multithread could speed it up? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It all depends on how big the computation you are doing is.  It is not always faster to use more threads.  It costs some time for each additional thread you spawn up.  Each thread will do some work, but sometimes it is quicker for a single thread to do all the work than to spawn up additional threads.  I'm not sure what you are computing... if you could give a little extra info on that I could give you more specific insight.

Comment: This is really really helpful, Travis. My group is trying to use the built-in MLlib packages in Spark to run machine learning algorithms. Right now we are experimenting on test data sets of around 1mill rows. We aim at a low prediction errors as well as a fast running speed. (We have gigabytes data coming in everyday, so the datasets can be potentially very big). We have compared Spark to sklearn packages in Python, it looks like running in local Spark (2.5min) is much slower than using the sklearn packages alone(30s). Don't why this is the case. Thanks a ton! The help is very much appreciated

Comment: It may be the case that 1 mill rows is small for Spark.  The power of spark really comes through when you're doing computation that is too big for a single computer (sklearn ~30s means it is pretty feasible for 1 computer to do the job).  Another factor is probably that sklearn is highly optimized (possibly running segments of compiled code) whereas (as far as I know) the spark+python is still interpreted (so slower than compiled code).

Comment: Thank you. This makes much more sense now. Is this also why that it's much slower for Spark+python to run some of the transformations such as map() comparing with the map() function in python alone? because we need to first go through spark then python?

Comment: Yes, spark will have a start-up cost (to create all of the process control structure, scheduling, etc).  Assuming you are using a linux machine, watch "top" as the process runs.  You'll see that spark spawns a bunch of java processes that handle the scheduling/which task gets which data, etc.  Starting those processes costs at least a couple seconds.  Then, those processes keep running while your map/reduce/etc tasks are running.  Also, the moving data from task to task has a cost... this movement might not be necessary in a standalone (single thread) job.

Comment: Very very helpful. Saved my life. I appreciate your help and explanations a lot.